# Setting array value in backbone.js initialize function

Tags: backbone.js

I'm trying to set an array value in a backbone.js model initialize function. In the line that starts with 'this.set...' I get a 'unexpected string' error. Is it not possible to set array values this way?

Thanks!

```
var bGenericItem = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: {
        attrArray: new Array({'item_id': '', 'type': '', 'name':''})
    },
    initialize: function(){
        // Set the id to cid for now
        this.set({ attrArray["item_id"]: this.cid });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do doesn't make any sense. Your `defaults` is an array which holds a single object:

```
defaults: {
    attrArray: [
        { item_id: '', type: '', name: '' }
    ]
},
```

You'd use an array if you wanted to hold a list of attribute objects. But, if you had a list of attribute objects, which one's `item_id` would you expect `attrArray['item_id']` to refer to? Are you assuming that `attrArray` will always be initialized to the default value and that no one would ever send an `attrArray` in as part of your model's initial data? If so, you'd want something more like this:

```
// Use a function so that each instance gets its own array,
// otherwise the default array will be attached to the prototype
// and shared by all instances.
defaults: function() {
    return {
        attrArray: [
            { item_id: '', type: '', name: '' }
        ]
    };
},
initialize: function() {
    // get will return a reference to the array (not a copy!) so
    // we can modify it in-place.
    this.get('attrArray')[0]['item_id'] = this.cid;
}
```

Note that you'll run into some issues with array attributes that require special handling:

1. `get('attrArray')` will return a reference to the array that is inside the model so modifying that return value will change the model.
2. Things like `a = m.get('attrArray'); a.push({ ... }); m.set('attrArray', a)` won't work the way you expect them to, the `set` won't notice that the array has changed (because it hasn't, `a == a` is true after all) so you won't get `"change"` events unless you clone the `attrArray` somewhere between `get` and `set`.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with your code

1: The `defaults` setting is an object literal which means the value that you assign to it is set as soon as it's defined. You need to set your defaults to a function, instead of a literal value. This will ensure each model instance gets it's own copy of the default values, instead of sharing a copy across every model instance.

2: You should also not use `new Array`, just use an array literal syntax `[]`. But you're not really using an array in this code, so I removed the array wrapper for now.

3: You can't access `attrArray` directly. You must get it from the model's attributes and then update it

```
var bGenericItem = Backbone.Model.extend({

    defaults: function(){
      return {
        attrArray: {'item_id': '', 'type': '', 'name':''}
      };
    },
    initialize: function(){
        // Set the id to cid for now
        var arr = this.get("attrArray");
        arr["item_id"] = this.cid;
    }
});
```

Comment: d'oh! i removed the array wrapper as it doesn't make sense to me :P